# Combobox with separator opening at the position of the separator

Tags: wpf, combobox, separator

I'm using a combobox containing 2 lists of items, separated by a separator.
I construct it this way:

```
public static ObservableCollection<object> Merge<T, U>(IEnumerable<T> collection1, IEnumerable<U> collection2, bool includeSeparator = true)
{
    if (collection1 == null || collection2 == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(collection1 == null ? "collection1" : "collection2");
    }

    List<object> tmp = new List<object>();

    tmp.AddRange(collection1.Cast<object>());

    if (includeSeparator)
    {
        tmp.Add(string.Empty);
    }

    tmp.AddRange(collection2.Cast<object>());

    var ret = new ObservableCollection<object>(tmp);
    return ret;
}
```

And in the xaml:

```
<ComboBox 
    ItemsSource="{Binding Path=AllValues}" 
    SelectedValue="{Binding Path=SelectedId, Mode=TwoWay, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" 
    SelectedValuePath="Id"
    ItemTemplate="{StaticResource CustomItemTemplate}">

    <ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ComboBoxItem}}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding}" Value="">
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}">
                                <Separator HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" IsEnabled="False"/>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
</ComboBox>
```

It is working as expected, I have a separator present where inserted in the list.
The problem is that when `SelectedId` is null, the combobox opens showing the separator at the top (i.e. the scrollbar is scrolled to have the separator at the top of the list), as in the following picture.

[image]

Do you know any way to have the list opening at the top ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest solution would be to change the separator item value to something that will return a non-null, but invalid, Id selection e.g. using int.MinValue in an anonymous type:

```
tmp.Add(new { Id = int.MinValue });
```

For this you will also need to change the DataTrigger to:

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Id}" Value="{x:Static System:Int32.MinValue}">
```

Comment: Recently encountered this issue myself, and this solution worked perfectly.